# Drupal 7.x is crashing the server by httpd requests

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7

Everytime the cache is cleared using the backend tools, or any module is being enabled, an HTTPD requests is killing the server by overloading it by hundred,

[httpd request](http://phptest.borninteractive.net/Capture.PNG)

[load average](http://phptest.borninteractive.net/Capture1.PNG)

once this happens only Forceful Reboot for the server would fix it,

could anyone show me the way how to see which link is being called, and how to track the issue?

No weird modules are installed just the usual, which are: CHAOS TOOLS, INPUT VALIDATION, SEO, ADMINISTRATION MENU, etc.

Server is CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 standard , PHP 5.3, MySQL DB, DRUPAL 7.50, All modules are latest updated,

error logged in apache error log is :
***PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/database/database.inc:2204\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/database/database.inc(2204): PDOStatement->execute(Array)\n#1 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/database/database.inc(683): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)\n#2 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/database/database.inc(2383): DatabaseConnection->query('SELECT expire, ...', Array, Array)\n#3 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/lock.inc(167): db_query('SELECT expire, ...', Array)\n#4 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/lock.inc(146): lock_may_be_available('theme_registry:...')\n#5 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/theme.inc(449): lock_acquire('theme_registry:...')\n#6 /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc(455): ThemeRegistry->set(Array)\n#7 [internal function]: DrupalCacheArray->__destruct()\n#8 {main}\n  thrown in /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/database/database.inc on line 2204, referer: http: //m.facebook.com/***

Comment: server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting

Comment: This article https://www.drupal.org/node/85768 may be helpful, and worth checking `PHP memory limit` in status report and increase that as per your site.. (`ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` in settings.php)

Comment: I have the following settings: Max Requests Per Child: 10000 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100 Timeouts  -  Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5   -   max_execution_time 3600  -  max_file_uploads 20  -max_input_nesting_level    64  -  max_input_time 3600  -  max_input_vars 2000  - mysql.max_links Unlimited - mysql.max_persistent  Unlimited  - memory_limit 360M   couldn't find the max_allowed_packet

Comment: I have the following settings: Max Requests Per Child: 10000 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100 Timeouts  -  Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5   -   max_execution_time 3600  -  max_file_uploads 20  -max_input_nesting_level    64  -  max_input_time 3600  -  max_input_vars 2000  - mysql.max_links Unlimited - mysql.max_persistent  Unlimited  - memory_limit 360M  - max_allowed_packet  268M